# postfix access subdomain format

Tags: postfix

I need to allow a domain to bypass my RBL checks.  I use:
check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/client_checks,

That works fine except I needed to add outbound.protection.outlook.com. I dont' seem to be getting a match on it.  I have it in my access file as shown below:

`outbound.protection.outlook.com  OK`

Can I go that deep on subdomains?  Manual says:

```
   .domain.tld
          Matches  subdomains  of  domain.tld,  but  only  when the string
          smtpd_access_maps  is   not   listed   in   the   Postfix   par-
          ent_domain_matches_subdomains configuration setting.*
```

Wasn't sure if I could only do

`.outlook.com    OK`

to match any subdomain

Trying to match:

`RCPT from mail-m6nam10on2120.outbound.protection.outlook.com[40.107.93.120]`

Postfix version 2.2.10
main.cf:parent_domain_matches_subdomains = smtpd_access_maps

Comment: I think I found the issue.  Maybe a typo in my access list, not sure.  But I figured out how to test an entry and I'm getting a "positive hit" now using:  postmap -q 'outbound.protection.outlook.com' hash:/etc/postfix/sender_checks

Answer (score 0):

Use client checks, not sender checks, seems to have been my problem.